TP Link Deco Router gets killed when Mac Mini is powered on
I'm facing a issue for quite a few months now,
My internet connection gets killed when I turn on my Mac Mini.
I verified that my ISP isn't failing by checking the lights on the modem - which tend to remain in green (I've tried troubleshooting it with my ISP Service Providers as well).
However, my TP Link Deco router configured with PPPoE to that Modem shows internet failure and displays the red light - after my Mac and Windows laptop is powered on, both of which are connected via Ethernet.
Attaching a schematic diagram of the network setup:

I've seen others face similar issues in:
https://community.netgear.com/t5/Nighthawk-Wi-Fi-5-AC-Routers/Mac-Mini-on-LAN-kills-home-network-when-Mac-goes-to-sleep/m-p/2231540
Not sure how to go ahead on this.
UPDATE:
I found that my ASUS Wifi router was not setup as Access Point, I've updated the configurations and monitoring for any network lapses.
Update 8/14:
Changed the wordings, no longer facing this issue with my Laptop, its the Mac Mini causing the network to get killed when I switch it on when the Router is turned on.
The workaround I'm relying on is that I wait for the network to be established on my Access Point and then switch on the Mac Mini

Which parts of your network remain reachable and which are not?

Wild guess, but I'm pretty sure one of your equipement is doing a broadcast storm. Recheck the network configuration and be sure they use the right settings

@grawity_u1686 - The TP-Link Wifi Router stops providing internet access, the network is still active but no internet access - all devices remain reachable.

@Maslie - I did have Internet Sharing On, on my Mac which has been turned off, post that too I did face this issue.
On another note, I have checked my Asus Wifi router, and it was not set up as an access point, currently did that change and monitoring for any disruptions right now.

I do not really understand why do you use a cat6 ethernet cable to connect your wi-fi rooter to a gbe switch that also connect to another rooter, this is like a spaghetti network. Pretty sure you just remove those cable and it will work

Its because there are no other ports remaining on my TP Link Wifi router, and I have a Phillips Hue Hub and a RasPi connected to it via lan.
FYI. I haven't seen any drops in network since I changed the router settings on the Asus, I'm thinking that's probably it..

Try to directly connect the ISP modem on the switch directly and then connect both of your Wi-Fi access point the switch instead

@Maslie That doesn't make sense. A modem is not a router. There's nothing wrong with the OP's setup.

@ChanganAuto he connect an AP to a switch to reconnect it with an AP, this shouldn't work

If you refer the diagram, my TP Link WiFi Router is configured to the ISP Modem and setup with PPPoE, The ISP Modem cannot be connected to the switch and distributed to two Wifi routers, if I do so, I'll have to configure PPPoE on either one of the WiFi Routers - which would leave the other branch dead w/o any internet.

Well, check if you get an ip address from your routeur, and send us the result or at least a reproduction

Could you clarify what you are trying to communicate by the word "supposedly" in the sentence "My internet connection gets killed when I supposedly turn on my..."? Also, is this "Mac Mini/ Windows 11 Dell Laptop" some rare hybrid device? If you are talking about two different computers and want to indicate they BOTH have the SAME or SIMILAR impacts, a more clear statement would be "...when I turn on either my Mac Mini or my Dell laptop running Windows 11".

That should clear things up @music2myear
